# Unit testing RxJava + Retrofit call inside the method

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit2, rx-java2

The method I want to test contains of two calls to the retrofit service:

```
 internal fun poll(): Completable {
    return presenceService.askForFrequency(true).toObservable()
            .flatMap { it -> Observable.interval(it.frequency, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io()) }
            .flatMapCompletable { _ -> presenceService.sendHeartbeat() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retry()
}
```

The `presenceService` is injected in the class, so I provide the mocked one for the test:

```
val frequency = PublishSubject.create<Presence>()
val heartbeat = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
val mockPresenceService = mock<PresenceService> {
    on { askForFrequency(any()) } doReturn frequency
    on { sendHeartbeat() } doReturn heartbeat
}
```

The test, that checks that `askForFrequency` method is called works correctly, but test that checks that the polling request is sent never works:

```
@Test
fun presenceService_sentHeartbeat() {
    RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { scheduler }

    frequency.onNext(Presence(1)) //polls with 1s interval
    heartbeat.onNext(Unit)
    presenceMaintainer.onActivityResumed(any())
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    verify(mockPresenceService).askForFrequency(true) //works correctly
    verify(mockPresenceService).sendHeartbeat() //never works
}
```

The logs from the unit test run are:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
presenceService.sendHeartbeat();

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
presenceService.askForFrequency(true);
```

The question is: **how to test that the second method (`sendHeartbeat`) is also called (possibly several times)**?

Meanwhile I found out that the problem lies in the second flatmap, because the test for this method works correctly (verifies that method was called 60 times):

```
 internal fun pollTest(): Observable<Presence> {
    return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap { it -> presenceService.askForFrequency(true).toObservable() }
}

@Test
fun presenceService_sentHeartbeat() {
    frequency.onNext(Presence(1))
    val result = arrayListOf<Unit>()
    presenceMaintainer.pollTest().subscribe({ t -> result.add(Unit) })
    Thread.sleep(60*1000)
    println(result.size)
    verify(mockPresenceService, Times(60)).askForFrequency(true)
}
```

But when I change the order of the calls to `askForFrequency -> map to interval -> map each tick to poll call`, test stops working and mock is called only once.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Observable.interval()` runs on the computation scheduler, and not the io scheduler. That means, that the 2 second wait will be run in real time, so your test will finish 2 seconds before the call to `sendHeartBeat()`.

Comment: Thank you! But if I add the ```RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { scheduler }``` or specify ```Schedulers.io``` in the interval call, it does not work either.

Comment: While it might be a of a pain to setup, my own experience is to pass in the schedulers that `interval()`, `delay()`, `debounce()` operators will run on. It makes testing much easier.